# Paypal create sandbox transaction

Tags: api, transactions, paypal

Anyone know how to create a transaction in the paypal sandbox?

It keeps saying go to my transactions software... all over it says my transaction software.  Thing is.. I don't have transaction software. I'm just trying to get the details of a transaction.  :)

I have an app that integrates with several back ends (ebay, westfield, google, amazon... ) if someone buys something from there, using paypal, I get a transaction ID.  I want to be able to retrieve the details of the paypal transaction because (god love em) they allow the user to change the ship to address or add special instructions, but they don't pass that info back to the "merchant".

I was thinking I'd create a test user in the sandbox and then see if I can get the details of a transaction, sadly I don't see a way to create a transaction.

Anyone find their docs equally mystifying?  I am in Nod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create another test account ie one account will act as seller and other will act as buyer.

From sellers Paypal account, you will have to create button.

Steps to create PayPal button:

- Login to your seller's test account in sandbox.
- Click on '**Merchant Services**' tab.
- There you will find **Create PayPal payment button**
- Fill out the form as per your requirement.

This will generate a HTML script.

Create a HTML file and copy paste this HTML script.
Open the HTML file, You will get a Paypal Button.

Click it and accept transaction by buyers PayPal account.

Comment: Ha haa!  PROGRESS =  404  * https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/merchant

Comment: 404 WORK_AROUND => https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/general-support/internal-error-sandbox-accounts  then search  "If you are trying to access this page to create payment"